# Facebook Permissions

Tags: facebook

I'm developing an app for a fan page. How can I post something from the app to the fan page wall? What permissions do I need to ask from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the `publish_stream` permission. Read all about that and other extended permissions at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: Yes, but how do you give the app that access to the page? Normally you give an app permissions when you log in to it via Facebook. But the "page" never logs in, so that path doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to obtain an access token for the page using the manage_pages permissions. Using that access token, you POST to the `/me/feed` endpoint. Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/